# Is there any performance bench-marking tools for HTML5 Web Apps?

Tags: html, cordova, mobile

Is there any performance bench-marking tools or best practices available for testing the mobile Web Apps?

Answer (score 1):

Google chrome has a profiler.  That can help, unless you are really looking for bottlenecks in another browser.

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/cpu-profiling

Answer (score 0):

You could measure the execution time of your major code blocks to find bottlenecks, along the lines of the code below. Running my app with this kind of measurement on a target mobile device then inspecting the log file to find the execution times helped me to increase the performance of my app considerably.

```
MeasureExecution = {
    timers: {},
    start: function(name){
        MeasureExecution.timers[name] = new Date().getTime();
    },
    stop: function(name){
        console.log("Execution time for '"+name+"'="+Math.abs(MeasureExecution.timers[name] - new Date().getTime())+"ms");
        delete MeasureExecution.timers[name];
    }
};

MyApp = {
  init: function(){
      // Do some initialisation stuff
      MeasureExecution.start("init");
      MyApp.doExpensiveStuff(); 
      MeasureExecution.stop("init");

      // Do some asynchronous stuff
      for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
          MyApp.startAsync(i);
      }         
  },

  doExpensiveStuff: function(){
      for(var i=0; i<10000; i++){
        for(var j=0; j<10000; j++){
        }    
      }
  },

  startAsync: function(id){
      MeasureExecution.start("async-"+id);
      window.setTimeout(function(){          
        MyApp.doAsync(id);                                 
      }, Math.floor(Math.random() *100));          
  },
  doAsync: function(id){
      MyApp.doExpensiveStuff();       
      MeasureExecution.stop("async-"+id);
  }     
};

MyApp.init();
```